# Checkbox in tableview section header

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

How to implement checkbox in tableview section header. my code is,

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *tempView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,200,300,244)];
    tempView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

     UIButton *leftSecCheckBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [leftSecCheckBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_empty.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [leftSecCheckBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkmark_Tick.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [leftSecCheckBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(22,-2, 26, 26)];
    [leftSecCheckBtn addTarget:self
               action:@selector(leftSectionCheckBox:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [tempView addSubview:leftSecCheckBtn];

}

-(void)leftSectionCheckBox:(id)sender
{   
    UIButton *selectedButton = (UIButton *) sender;
    {
        if([selectedButton isSelected ]==YES)
        {
            [selectedButton setSelected:NO];
        }
        else
        {
            [selectedButton setSelected:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

Added button in ViewForHeader function,But, the button's image is not changing,??

Comment: Is it give some error?? make break point and debug it..

Comment: no error in this code. my problem is , the button is images is not changing.

Comment: Is that the actual code in viewForHeaderInSection?  There's no `return tempView;` at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this could help:

```
-(void)leftSectionCheckBox:(UIButton *)sender  {  

sender.selected = !sender.isSelected;
if([selectedButton isSelected ]==YES)  [selectedButton setSelected:NO];
else  [selectedButton setSelected:YES];
}
```

or you can do this:

```
-(void)leftSectionCheckBox:(id)sender {  
for (UIButton * selectedButton in [[tableView headerViewForSection:0]subviews]) {
    if ([selectedButton isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
       if([selectedButton isSelected ]==YES) [selectedButton setSelected:NO];
       else  [selectedButton setSelected:YES];
      }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    -(void)leftSectionCheckBox:(id)sender
    {   
        UIButton *selectedButton = (UIButton *) sender;

            if([selectedButton isSelected ]==YES)
            {
                [selectedButton setSelected:NO];
                [leftSecCheckBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_empty.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
            else
            {
                [selectedButton setSelected:YES];
                [leftSecCheckBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkmark_Tick.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
      }
```

I updated answer it one of the way. Otherwise you have to do it via interface builder.

Comment: Would you think It will go with in this condition  UIButton *selectedButton = (UIButton *) sender;
    {
        if([selectedButton isSelected ]==YES)
        {
            [selectedButton setSelected:NO];
        }
        else
        {
            [selectedButton setSelected:YES];
        }
    }

Comment: Do you mean the extra curly braces?  They don't make a difference to the execution flow.  There is no condition there.

Answer (score 0):

Set your `tempView` user interaction enabled,

```
[tempView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

And you can minimize your method like,

```
-(void)leftSectionCheckBox:(UIButton *)selectedButton
{    
  selectedButton.selected = !selectedButton.selected;
}
```